# react-native-geocoding shows error not getting coordinates

Tags: react-native, geocoding

I am using https://github.com/marlove/react-native-geocoding to get coordinates in react-native.

**Sample code**

```
`Geocoder.from("visakhapatnam,andhra pradesh,india")
.then(json => {
var location = json.results[0].geometry.location;
console.log("location",location)
})
.catch(error => console.warn("routeMap Err",error));`
```

**I am getting error**

*{"code": 4, "message": "Error from the server while geocoding. The received datas are in the error's 'origin' field. Check it for more informations.", "origin": {"error_message": "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started", "results": [], "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"}}*

Answer (score 1):

To use the Geocoding API you must have an API key. The API key is a unique identifier that is used to authenticate requests associated with your project for usage and billing purposes.

To get an API key:

1. Visit the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/overview).
2. Click the project drop-down and select or create the project for
   which you want to add an API key.
3. Click the menu button  and select **APIs & Services > Credentials.**
4. On the Credentials page, click **Create credentials > API key**. **The API
   key created** dialog displays your newly created API key.
5. Click **Close**. The new API key is listed on the Credentials page under
   API keys.
       (Remember to restrict the API key before using it in production.)

---

OR You need try enable billing like an error message.

1. Go to the Payment Account Management page in the Google Cloud
   Platform Console and log in.
2. Select the My Projects tab to display the list of projects and the
   payment accounts associated with each project.
3. In the list of projects, locate the project for which you want to
   re-enable payments, and then click the menu (more_vert) next to it.
4. Select Change payment and select the destination payment account you
   want.

Comment: I had restricted the API key. but I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

did you provide api key to geocoded like this
Geocoder.init('your api key'); // use a valid API key

Comment: yes I had given API key Geocoder.init('AIzaSyDrXtB60HP2C1MWK*******');

Comment: So what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my google cloud free trial plan ended. When I upgraded to Blaze plan the error stopped happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';
import {keys} from '../env';
```

> First ensure your billing info and geocoding API are properly setup
> and enabled.Then set up code to grant permission to avert future
> issues

```
const _getCurrentPosition = async () => {
    Geocoder.init(keys.GOOGLE_MAP_APIKEY); // initialized with a valid API key
    const status = await locationPermission(); // write the function
    if (status === 'granted') {
      const location = await getCurrentLocation(); // write the function
      console.log('Location Permission granted!');
      console.log({currentLoc: location});
     
      Geocoder.from({
        latitude: location.latitude,
        longitude: location.longitude,
      })
        .then(addressJson => {
          const _location = addressJson.results[0].formatted_address;
          console.log('location_', _location);
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error));

      //or for non-geometry positions (plain addresses)
      //**IMPORTANT** make sure the address is valid to avoid errors
      //one way to do this is to first google a valid address
       Geocoder.from("visakhapatnam")
        .then(addressJson => {
          const _location = addressJson.results[0].geometry.location;
          console.log('location_', _location);
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error));
    } else {
      console.log('Permission not grantedd!');
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    _getCurrentPosition();
  }, []);
```

Don't forget to ALWAYS consult the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geocoding